# F# Entity Type Provider type scope

Tags: visual-studio, f#, type-providers

I'm trying to use SqlEntiyConnection to generate types from a MySql/MariaDb database using:

```
type UserService = SqlEntityConnection<Provider=provider, ConnectionString=connectionstring, Pluralize = true>
```

Where provider That declaration gives the following error message

```
"The provided types generated by this use of a type provider may not be used from other F# assemblies and should be marked internal or private. Consider using 'type internal TypeName = ...' or 'type private TypeName = ...'".
```

This seems to indicate that I will be unable to use any of the provided types outside the of the scope I declare it in. Is there a way to declare the type provider publicly so that I can use these types in public functions?

Comment: Do you need/have to use the `SqlEntityConnection` type provider? E.g. can you use [SQLProvider](http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/)?

Comment: I had attempted to use that earlier, but when I installed the package, for some reason couldn't detect that it was there.  Namespace FSharp.Data.Sql could not be found.

Comment: Is what I'm asking to do with SqlEntityConnection impossible?

Comment: Actually I got SQLProvider to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per s952163's comment, I went with with SQLProvider instead of SQLEntityConnection.